Can Peter Enns still be considered an orthodox protestant?
Peter Enns was expelled from the Westminster Seminary due to this positions judged too liberal in his book Inspiration and Incarnation: Evangelicals and the Problem of the Old Testament (2005).
This article contains a comment of this affair, and provides "two reports authored by the conservative members of the Westminster faculty, in which they explain why Enns' views are in conflict with biblical and historic Christian teachings on the nature of Scripture."
While Peter Enns views can still nonetheless be considered conservative (1), there is especially a passage where he expresses his views on Calvinism, which seem to me to be pretty compatible with the orthodox current of protestantism of which principle is to stick with the first reformers (Calvin, Luther) methods and thoughts.
Here is the passage, from a long article on Calvinism published on Biologos:

In its best iterations, Calvinism is a “third way” that negotiates between the extremes of (1) a dismissal of Scripture as God’s word because of it obvious human dimension, and (2) a dismissal of the historical dimension of Scripture in an effort to protect its divine dimension. The first option is typically referred to as “liberalism” and the second as “fundamentalism.” That is a bit reductionistic as far as I am concerned, but those are the popularly accepted labels.


The Calvinist legacy, at least in principle, is well suited to avoid these extremes for one simple reason. It embraces the “incarnate” nature of Scripture, that it is God’s word but in human form. Scripture is a divine, inspired text, and also on every page bears the unmistakable, discernable, and wonderful stamp of the time and space bound human beings who by inspiration produced it.
And this stamp is not to be observed theoretically nor as an unfortunate concession. Rather it is an affirmation that the human element of Scripture is worthy of the most careful and thoughtful reflection, with potentially important, theologically significant payoff. This is a distinctive and vital mark of the Calvinist legacy.

From there, can Peter Enns still be considered an orthodox protestant?

It would have been helpful if, as part of your research, you had included a link to the Western Seminary and, in particular, to what they published as a reason for their expulsion of Peter Enns. Without that information, the question seems, to me, to be somewhat a matter of opinion.

@NigelJ Thank you very much. Edited.

I am still searching for just one single quotation of scripture or a single reference to the bible in the article ""Inspiration and Incarnation:" A Response,". Bucketloads of theological terminology and historical 'positions'. But, as yet, I can find not a single argument that puts the words of Peter Enns against the actual words of scripture. Thus, to myself, all of this is just people arguing about their own opinions and disagreeing with one another's loyalties. As such, this appears, to me, to be off-topic as a 'matter of opinion'.

@NigelJ In fact, this is quite also what I feel this affair is about...

In that case, it is best left alone. And we can get on with better things . . . . . .

Frankly there is no such thing as a "orthodox protestant". Protestantism contains literally hundreds of denominations, many of which disagree with each other profoundly and consider others within the group to be heretics.

@DJClayworth Protestants do not often consider other Protestants to be heretics! (And there are also only a dozen or so major sub-branches, not hundreds.) There are some big divisions within Protestantism, such as Reform vs Arminian, but they don't consider the other side to be heretics. I'd say that upholding the Four Solas is a solid mark of Protestant orthodoxy.

I didn't say "major sub-branches". There are dozens of different denominations of Baptists alone. Heck, there are a few dozen kinds of Mennonites. "Heretic" may be a little strong, but plenty of denominations consider each other "not orthdox".

@DJClayworth So what if there are dozens of Baptist denominations? Many of them would have identical theology and practices! All it means is that they're regional rather than global. Having lots of denominations isn't by itself any evidence of disunity.

You refer to a book with a 2005 date, and quote from a Biologos web-page where the author expresses his view on Calvinism. You certainly have me at a disadvantage there, as I neither have the book nor do I feel inclined to read that long web-article.
From what little has been quoted, the author of that book is not really in danger of being considered "no longer orthodoxly Protestant". In many Protestant circles that are viewed as being 'orthodox', having the view that the Bible "contains" the word of God (as opposed to every word being "God-breathed and inspired by the Holy Spirit") is the predominant view. And few theologians bat an eyelid at that.
However, to be 'expelled' from the Westminster Seminary for his book showing too 'liberal' a position, is quite another matter. He might well not be an orthodoxly Reformed Protestant, but that would not stop him being considered orthodoxly Protestant by many others. Whose opinion matters here? Who should we listen to, or read?
We will all be judged, and that by God's already-given Word of God who became flesh. He asked his followers who they believed him to be, and rejoiced when Peter declared him to the Christ, the Son of God (an ascription of deity). Jesus said that fact had been revealed to him by the Father. So, where do we get our 'revelations' from? Who do we believe? If not the written word of God, what other source is there for discovering just who Jesus really is?
Let whoever wishes to write about such topics as Peter Enns does, do so, knowing that Jesus said we shall be judged for every careless word (Matthew 12:36). If he has written carelessly about the word of God, he will answer to the Word of God for that - not to me or you. But we have to decide who we are going to allow to influence our beliefs regarding the Bible. If we spent more time studying the Bible than we do human writings about the Bible, would we not be in a better position to decide about the Bible? The Westminster Seminary has a duty to take action they deem necessary to uphold their theological stance, but I think on these words:

"Who art thou that judgest another man's servant? To his own master he
standeth or falleth". Romans 14:4 A.V.

